# "import type" is causing unit tests to fail

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, storybook

I have two components that looks something like this:

**Parent Component**

```js
@Component({
  template: '',
  providers: [
    { provide: PARENT_COMPONENT, useExisting: forwardRef(() => ParentComponent) }
  ]
})
export class ParentComponent { }
```

**Child Component**

```js
@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class MyComponent {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PARENT_COMPONENT) private readonly parentComponent: ParentComponent
  ){}

}
```

Injection token:

```js
export const PARENT_COMPONENT = new InjectionToken<ParentComponent>('ParentComponentToken');
```

In the child component, when I do an import like this:

```js
import type { ParentComponent } from '../parent.component';
```

My unit tests all break and throw the following error:

> ReferenceError: ParentComponent is not defined

However, my storybook works and the component works just fine.

If I change the import by removing the `type` so it looks like this:

```js
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent.component';
```

Then storybook doesn't work but the unit tests do work. Why is this causing me issues? How can I fix it?

If I were to change the constructor to use `any` instead of `ParentComponent`, both the unit tests and storybook works. However, I don't really want to do this because then the code isn't strongly typed.

Comment: Curious why you are providing the parent component to itself? Is this a storybook convention?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think I am providing it to itself...

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading... In the component decorator, you have a providers array with a parent component injection token providing forward ref to the the same component

Comment: You don't want to import just the type here. You need an implementation. So...erm..don't use `import type`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Maybe I am doing it wrong (it does work)? I am trying to provide a reference to the parent in the child so the child can access it's parent.

Comment: *Why is this causing me issues?* [import type only imports declarations to be used for type annotations and declarations. It always gets fully erased, so there’s no remnant of it at runtime.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html)

Comment: But removing it breaks storybook (no errors are given in storybook either).

Comment: Also, If i replace `parentComponent: ParentComponent` in the constructor with `parentComponent: any` both storybook and the unit tests work. However this isn't typed well.